# Code for keeping a list of the "Pose" that Turtlebot has visited

Tags: ros, 2d-pose-estimate, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello experts,

i am trying to write a node in cpp that keeps track of the positions that my Turtlebot already traveled to. the reason is that I want my node to compare any given nav goals against the said (visited) pose list and accepts the given nav goal if it is not already in the list. - what im trying to achieve here is a 2D full coverage method. (got to be a challenge to me!!!)

im using a kobuki base, hokuyo lidar, gmapping to build a map in ros indigo.

According to tutorials i came up with the code to retrieve the robot's pose in the /map frame, now i wanna save it and as im new to cpp programming, can anyone can help me with the piece of code that i need to add to my node in order to make it happen?

a piece of the Code where pose is looked up:

```
tf::StampedTransform transform;
        try{
            ros::Time now=ros::Time::now();
            listener.waitForTransform("/map","/base_link",now,ros::Duration(3.0));
            listener.lookupTransform("/map","/base_link",ros::Time(0), transform);
            ROS_INFO("Got a transform! x = %f, y = %f",transform.getOrigin().x(),transform.getOrigin().y()); //to check results
        }
        catch (tf::TransformException ex){
        
            ROS_ERROR("%s" ,ex.what());
       }
```

**UPDATE:**

Today I made a fresh installed of hector_slam on my Indigo to work with trajectory_server, everything works perfect with hector_mapping as i get a consistent map, good pose updates, etc. But the hector_trajectory_server doesnt seem to work. i use the same instructions as Stefan gave below in his comment along with hector_mapping.

My tf tree: **map > base_link > laser**

output of `rosservice call trajectory` is a series of

```
  header: 
    seq: 0
    stamp: 
      secs: 1454454715
      nsecs: 262124169
    frame_id: /map
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
```

**UPDATE2** Launch file:

```
    <launch>
      <arg name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" default="scanmatcher_frame"/>
      <arg name="base_frame" default="/base_link"/>
      <arg name="odom_frame" default="/base_link"/>
      <arg name="pub_map_odom_transform" default="true"/>
      <arg name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" default="5"/>
      <arg name="scan_topic" default="scan"/>
      <arg name="map_size" default="2048"/>
      <arg name="trajectory_source_frame_name" default="/base_link"/>
      <arg name="trajectory_update_rate" default="4"/>
      <arg name="trajectory_publish_rate" default="0.25"/>
      <arg name="map_file_base_name" default="hector_slam_map"/>
      <arg name="map_file_path" default="$(find test_nav)/maps"/>  

      <node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping" output="screen">
        
        <!-- Frame names -->
        <param name="map_frame" value="/map" />
        <param name="base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame)" />
        <param name="odom_frame" value="$(arg odom_frame)" />
        
        <!-- Tf use -->
        <param name="use_tf_scan_transformation" value="true"/>
        <param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="false"/>
        <param name="pub_map_scanmatch_transform" value="false"/>
        <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="$(arg pub_map_odom_transform)"/>
        
        <!-- Map size / start point -->
        <param name="map_resolution" value="0.05"/>
        <param name="map_size" value="$(arg map_size)"/>
        <param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
        <param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
        <param name="map_multi_res_levels" value="2" />
        
        <!-- Map update parameters -->
        <param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
        <param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.9" />    
        <param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.4"/>
        <param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />
        <param name="laser_z_min_value" value = "-1.0" />
        <param name="laser_z_max_value" value = "1.0" />
        <param name="laser_max_dist" value = "5.3" />
        <param name="laser_min_dist" value = "0.1" />
        
        <!-- Advertising config --> 
        <param name="advertise_map_service" value="true"/>
        
        <param name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" value="$(arg scan_subscriber_queue_size)"/>
        <param name="scan_topic" value="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
        
        <!-- Debug parameters -->
        <!--
          <param name="output_timing" value="false"/>
          <param name="pub_drawings" value="true"/>
          <param name="pub_debug_output" value="true"/>
        -->
        <param name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" value="$(arg tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name)" />
      </node>

      <node pkg="hector_trajectory_server" type="hector_trajectory_server" name="hector_trajectory_server" output="screen">
        <param name="target_frame_name" type="string" value="/map" />
        <param name="source_frame_name" type="string" value="$(arg trajectory_source_frame_name)" />
        <param name="trajectory_update_rate" type="double" value="$(arg trajectory_update_rate)" />
        <param name="trajectory_publish_rate" type="double" value="$(arg trajectory_publish_rate)" />
      </node>

      <node pkg="hector_geotiff" type="geotiff_node" name="hector_geotiff_node" output="screen" launch-prefix="nice -n 15">
        <remap from="map" to="/dynamic_map" />
        <param name="map_file_path" type="string" value="$(arg map_file_path)" />
        <param name="map_file_base_name" type="string" value="$(arg map_file_base_name)" />
        <param name="geotiff_save_period" type="double" value="45" />
        <param name="draw_background_checkerboard" type="bool" value="true" />
        <param name="draw_free_space_grid" type="bool" value="true" />
        <param name="plugins" type="string" value="hector_geotiff_plugins/TrajectoryMapWriter" />
      </node>

      <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_base_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /base_link 50"/> 
    
      <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_base_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 50"/>

</launch>
```

**UPDATE3:** here is an image created of the map created in Rviz by hector mapping. i start at the Blue marker and walk around the room to create the map, but as you can see the Path information is not there and `rosservice call trajectory` is not returning anything useful either. otherwise movements relative to frames are perfect despite im using a 10HZ lidar.
[Image:: hector_img.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14545269772713417.png)

**tf tree**  `pub_map_odom_transform` set to true.
[image: tf_tree]

Is there anything that i could be missing here or something has changed in the hector slam?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205014/code-for-keeping-a-list-of-the-%22pose%22-that-turtlebot-has-visited./) by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2015-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2015-03-15**:
Do you publish your position over `/odom` ? If yes it is really easy to achieve your goal.

Anyway there are many ways to get that information. If you have odom I ll tell you what I would do in that case.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-03-15**:
@Andromeda well, as u can see in the code I want to save the pose with regards to the `/map` frame that comes from gmapping. and yes my robot does publish the `/odom` info. - i'm a bit lost in the cpp coding aspect of it. save and retrieve (for comparing).

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-02-03**:
So in rviz the pose of the robot is tracked correctly with regards to the /map frame?

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2016-02-03**:
yes. works even better and faster than Gmapping for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[hector_trajectory_server](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_trajectory_server) allows keeping track of a robot's trajectory. It keeps track of a trajectory based on tf and publishes it as a [nav_msgs/Path](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html) that can directly be visualized in rviz.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-hector-slam
```

(if your are using indigo, otherwise substiture "indigo" with the ROS distro you use).

You can then use the package in one of your launch files like so:

```
  <node pkg="hector_trajectory_server" type="hector_trajectory_server" name="hector_trajectory_server" output="screen">
    <param name="target_frame_name" type="string" value="/map" />
    <param name="source_frame_name" type="string" value="/base_link" />
    <param name="trajectory_update_rate" type="double" value="4" />
    <param name="trajectory_publish_rate" type="double" value="0.25" />
  </node>
```

/edit: Your tf tree is wrong, there is a static transform publisher publishing the map->base_link transform (confusingly named `odom_base_broadcaster`). This job is supposed to be performed by hector_mapping. You should definitely comment that broadcaster out. Afterwards, hector_mapping should be publishing the necessary tf data in the output of view_frames.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2016-02-02**:
Hello dear Stefan, I tried this at the time you answered me and i could at least visualize the trajectory, today i tried it again with a fresh install of hector_slam and it seems that trajectory_server doesn't work. updated this question already, or should i post a new question? cheers.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-02-03**:
Please edit your original post with your launch file for the trajectory server. Do you get any debug output on your terminal (like tf failure warnings)?

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2016-02-03**:
updated, launch file is basically a working mix of the ones provided by the hector_slam samples. and no i dont get any errors or anything. I see the `/trajectory` topic and can add `path` to RViz but it doesnt visualize lines.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-02-03**:
I think you probably want to set pub_map_odom_transform to true.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2016-02-03**:
just did that, no luck with trajectory visualisation. do i need to remove the packages and do a clean install maybe?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-02-03**:
I don't think so, this really hasn't changed for a long time. Do you see the mapping process in rviz (i.e. do you see the base_link frame moving relative to /map)?

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2016-02-03**:
I just tried a clean install on my machine, also a new install on a VM Hydro with the same config. everything works perfectly movements relative to /map are precise. its just that the Trajectory info is not there, strange.  i posted an image of the resulted map in the post.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-02-03**:
The map actually can look plausible (and the poseupdate get written out) with pub_map_odom_transform set to false. Can you add the pdf output of "rosrun tf view_frames" to your post?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-02-03**:
See edited answer.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2016-02-03**:
Lovely! it worked. Thanks So MUCH. may i get a little clarification though? can Hector SLAM replace Gmapping as a slam solution? can it recover from failures like that in PF based slam? slow Gmapping updates and occasional jumps are causing us some problems & am looking for a faster solution.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-02-03**:
Yes, hector_mapping can be used as a drop-in replacement for gmapping. It does not track multiple hypotheses, but in many applications is reliable enough so this is not a disadvantage.